# When to use views and when to use stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, view

I am a application where number of reports are more. What i do for each report is that i create a mysql view and a mysql stored procedure. From front end php i give a call to stored procedure with where clause, based on this where clause i fetch results from the particular view. Recently i found out that it was causing performance issue. So i avoided views and wrote the same code in stored procedure and performance improved. So from that poit i am confused as to ideal situation when i should use Stored procedure and when i should use views.

And Does my scenario explained above really cause performance issue or was it problem at my end?

Comment: views will create table like structure using which you can navigate records in views. While stored procedure are compiled queries.

Answer (score 1):

Views in mysql are mainly for readability. They enable you to hide a possibly complex query over multiple tables into something that appears to be a single table.

I would suspect that the most likely cause is not the use of views themselves (although not sure they would help you in any way, while a stored procedure might well be more efficient), rather a view you are using is poorly optimised (maybe ignoring keys).